Which Fallout game organizations are "all six agencies" that issue bounties?
In the 2024 Fallout TV series (Season 1, Episode 2: "The Target"), The Ghoul (Walton Goggins) mentions that a bounty for Dr. Wilzig (Michael Emerson) came through “all six agencies.” 
What agencies is The Ghoul referring to? Given that Dr. Wilzig is a fugitive from the Enclave, I'm guessing it is one of the six.
For those familiar with the Fallout video games, is this a reference to specific organizations within the games? If so, can you identify these organizations and which Fallout game they made their first appearance in?

I think it's some unnamed bounty hunter association thingies. Some dudes you can post bounty at, acting as proxies. It's not like Enclave could put a bounty directly, for ex.

There is a mod to the game Hearts of Iron 4 called Old World Blues which has made an attempt to create a faction map covering as much of the western US as they can, based on all games up to but not including Fallout 4 (taking place on the east coast). They seem to be pretty hardcore fans, but I can't tell how much of the map that is "canon". However, nations and factions are not "agencies", so none of this might be relevant.

We can't yet be sure about this, but I believe based upon context that the agencies are bounty hunter groups, not factions from the games.
The Ghoul is a bounty hunter, and the men he originally got this bounty's information from were also bounty hunters:

"We got a proposition for ya. A bounty came down. A huge one. Enough to be a last score for me and whoever's with me."

He apparently has since had time to verify the bounty with his connections:

"Now, last night a bounty came through all six agencies. A hefty price, on the head of a man that fits the description of that fella right there."

If this is the case, we don't necessarily know enough to say which agencies these are. But the wasteland is brimming with people looking to make caps in all sorts of ways and this line doesn't really imply the agencies in question are related to game factions (a few of which would also be unlikely to have a presence on the west coast).

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide quotes to back up the "context?"

@DavidW Sure, updated a bit. How's that?

Better!  Good enough to propose an alternate theory anyway.

"the agencies are bounty hunter groups, not factions from the games." I see. In line with this, I've replaced the term "faction" with "organization" in my question.

My guess is
VAULT-TEC
Rob-Co
West-Tek
Big MT
REPPCON
ENCLAVE (Government)
Just from the 5 groups at the table in episode 8 and the enclave is basically the government or the continuation of the government.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question asked for more than just a list, can you [edit] in the requested details about these?

Factions on west coast
-Mr House (vault tec)
-Legion
-NCR
-Brotherhood
-Enclave
(Blank) maybe the great khans or institute (east coast but super into science) or someone else we’ve yet to meet.
Also Mr House may be dead because actions player can make in New Vegas but they can easily retcon that if they want. The stories heading to New Vegas season 2
Games: New Vegas, Fallout 4, Fallout 3, NCR forms sometime in fallout 1 or 2 keep in mind the show is linear so this is in further along time wise than all other games shady sands was NCR capital I’m assuming they became raiders after falling. Hope this helps

Hi. Could you edit this answer to tell us a bit more about these factions and/or include links to relevant web pages?

By going through most major factions in the games and some that were mentioned in the show my best bet would be: The Brotherhood of Steel, The Enclave, The Institution, The Minutemen, The Railroad and a major Raider faction such as New California Republic (post bomb drop). Hope this helped!

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide some links or background on what those factions are and where (source material) they come from?

Hi Max, you may want to take the [tour].
